# Mmap is not working for high address memory mapping?

Tags: linux, memory, mmap

I am trying to do

```
memory = (char *)mmap((void *)0X0000100000000000,(size_t)0xffffffff/8,PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE , MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS,4,0);
```

but its not mapping anything and returning 0. I need to map memory at high address in 64-bit machine.

Comment: Why do you need to "map memory at high address?"  What's the end goal?

Comment: I need to store values at that address for shadow mapping.

Answer (score 1):

This is not meant as a complete answer - more of a possible explanation:

0X0000100000000000 is 281474976710656.  Do you have that high a virtual memory address available?  Or stated another way: is that address valid in your OS?  I would guess the answer is no.

Is mmap actually returning MAP_FAILED (  (void *) -1 )?   Usually when you give mmap an address it does not like, you get MAP_FAILED and errno == EINVAL.  Did you check errno?

Note: 4 bytes is not the word length in a 64 bit OS, usually it is 8. A 4 byte word cannot address all of memory, for example.

Comment: I have a 64-bit os, so 64-bit memory address is valid for it ,0X0000100000000000 is 64-bit memory address. mmap is returning 0 for sure. i didn't said anything about 4-byte.